# DataGridView with BindingSource inline edit with stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have dataGridView1 with DataSource defined as BindingSource:

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dsGrid.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

where dsGrid is DataSet read from MSSQL DB with stored procedure.
As I set dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false, user can inline edit data.

I want to send whole edited row to stored procedure after user finishes editing, where parameters will be edited data. How can I do it?

I have class, which runs this procedure on actual SqlConnection. So my goal is to hook the moment of posting data and read edited data from grid. Than I can send them to DB.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the behaviour of a DataGrid set to ReadOnly = false, but could you use an IValueConverter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find easy straightforward solution. So I added editing column of DataGridViewButtonColumn class named Action, buttons with text Edit.

```
int _rowIndex = -1;
bool _edited = false;
.
.
.
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // it is button - column Action
    {
        if (_rowIndex >= 0) // not first editing
        {
            if (_rowIndex != e.RowIndex) // row change - cancel and begin elsewhere
            {
                // TODO: ask for save edited values
                endInlineEdit(_rowIndex);
                beginInlineEdit(e.RowIndex);
            }
            else // the same row
            {
                if (_edited) // is edited, so save
                {
                    saveToDB(e.RowIndex);
                }
                else // repeating same row editation
                {
                    beginInlineEdit(e.RowIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        else // editing first time
        {
            beginInlineEdit(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}

private void saveToDB(int rowIndex)
{     
    save to DB
    ...
    endInlineEdit(rowIndex);
}

private void beginInlineEdit(int rowIndex)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "Save";
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["FirstEditedColumn"];
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    _rowIndex = rowIndex;
    _edited = true;
}

private void endInlineEdit(int rowIndex)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "Edit";
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    _edited = false;
}

private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (_edited)
    {
        endInlineEdit(_rowIndex);
    }
}
```

So I did it manually. Not nice, but functionally.